# How to write reciprocal squared function shifted right by $3$ and down by $4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given a reciprocal squared function that is shifted right by $3$ and down by $4$, write this as a rational function.

---

I am uncertain how to denote this. My attempt:
$$\frac{1}{x^2-3}-4$$

But I need to show this as a rational function. Right now the $-4$ is disconnected from the fraction part.

Is it just this?:
$$\frac{1}{x^2-3-4}$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2-7}$$

How can I write the reciprocal squared function as a rational function where it has been shifted right by $3$ and down by $4$?

edit:
Is it?:
$$\frac{1}{(x-3)^2}+4$$

Comment: $\frac1{x-3}-4\ne\frac1{x-3-4}$

Comment: What's a reciprocal square function?  I think the confusion here stems from the fact that the wording is vague.  I really can't guess what is intended.  None of your functions reflect the "squared" so I assume they are all wrong, but who knows?

Comment: Is the reciprocal squared function referring to $\frac1{x^2}$? If so, then all your expressions are wrong.

Comment: Also if you want to shift a function $f(x)$ by $b$ units to the right, do $f(x+b)$. If you want to shift a function $g(x)$ by $b$ units down, then do $g(x)-b$. This should be enough information to determine the answer, no matter what your function is.

Comment: Hi, sorry I posted without denoting that. Updated now to be `x^2`

Comment: I think I might be a step closer with `(x-3)^2`?

Comment: All I get from this question is that you take the square function ($x\mapsto x^2$) and then you transform it by: (1) Taking the reciprocal, (2) Shifting the graph to the right by $3$, (3) Shifting the graph down by $4$. However ... In which *order* are those three transformations applied?

Comment: For context I am on this page in an online textbook at 'Try it #7' https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/5-6-rational-functions

Comment: I suspect what they mean is the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{(x - 3)^2} - 4$.  However, the way the question is phrased makes the sequence of transformations unclear.  Note that replacing $x$ by $x - 3$ shifts the graph to the right three units and subtracting $4$ from the expression shifts it down by $4$ units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is a reciprocal squared function: $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$$
$g$ is $f$ shifted by $a$ units to the right: $$g(x)=f(x-a)\\g(x)=\frac{1}{(x-a)^2}$$
$h$ is $g$ shifted by $b$ units down $$h(x) = g(x)-b\\h(x)=\frac{1}{(x-a)^2}-b$$
So if you shift $f$ by 3 units to the right and 4 units down you would get the following function $h$:
$$h(x)=\frac{1}{(x-3)^2}-4$$
Now to simplify the expression of $h$ or to make it a "rational function" you just have to find the common denominator of the 2 summands which is in this case $(x-3)^2$:
$$h(x)=\frac{1}{(x-3)^2}-\frac{4(x-3)^2}{(x-3)^2}=\frac{1-4(x^2-6x+9)}{(x-3)^2}\\h(x)=\frac{-4x^2+24x-35}{(x-3)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity call $u=(x-3)^2$ so that $h(x)=1/u + 4 = 1/u + 4u/u=(1+4u)/u$ and now substituting back in we have $h(x)=(1+4(x-3)^2)/(x-3)^2$ which is the quotient of two polynomials as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x\pm k)$ shifts a function to the left/right by $k$.  $f(x) \pm m$ shifts a function up/down by $m$.

So $f(x-3) + 4$ will shift a function to the right by $3$ and up by $4$.

So if $f([\color{blue}x]) = \frac 1{[\color{blue}x]^2}$

then $f([\color{red}{x-3}])+ 4 = \frac 1{[\color{red}{x-3}]^2} + 4$